# CSS class naming rules

Tags: css

I have 2 controls which must have 100% width. So I have a question what is better:

1) declare CSS style name for each control (CSS style will contain only `width: 100%` declaration)

2) declare only one CSS style name which will be applied to all widgets requiring 100% width?

I mean:

```
.myFirstWidget {
  width: 100%;
}
.mySecondWidget {
  width: 100%;
}
```

vs

> .maxWidthWidget {   width: 100%; }

Comment: I can't see why you would need more than one class for this.

Comment: This is mostly personal preference. There are cases where having too many css rules can become an issue (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx) but for most sites (I've only encountered 1 that had this issue and is a fairly large financial site) you won't come close to those limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .maxWidthWidget it will be easier to update a site if you stick to these naming conventions. Only separate if they ever need to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
.myFirstWidget,.mySecondWidget {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the one-class fits all. It's more descriptive as a name, and it's easier to maintain, and uses the principle of reusability. :-)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is:

```
.myFirstWidget, .mySecondWidget {
  width: 100%;
  /* Other shared properties... */
}
.myFirstWidget {
  /* Properties specific to this widget... */
}
.mySecondWidget {
  /* Properties specific to this widget... */
}
```